# Getting the sum of firebase values according to transaction type

Tags: java, android, firebase

I have a problem trying to sum up some values.

I have 2 categories for the sums:

1. IN
2. OUT

In my database I have stored values like this:

**TRANSACTIONS** >

............................."random key" >

.....................................................Transaction_Type: "IN"

.....................................................Transaction_Amount: "300"

............................."random key" >

.....................................................Transaction_Type: "IN"

.....................................................Transaction_Amount: "450"

............................."random key" >

.....................................................Transaction_Type: "OUT"

.....................................................Transaction_Amount: "250"

............................."random key" >

.....................................................Transaction_Type: "IN"

.....................................................Transaction_Amount: "700"

............................."random key" >

.....................................................Transaction_Type: "OUT"

.....................................................Transaction_Amount: "100"

---

I need to add all *"Transaction_Amount"* values according to their *"Transaction_Type"*, then display their sums in TextViews.

My current code:

Display all transactions in a recyclerView:

```
package com.fruitzalad.simplelogin;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.firebase.ui.database.SnapshotParser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;

public class Transactions extends Fragment {

TextView lblIN, lblOUT, lblInHand;
String TEST;

private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter adapter;
public RecyclerView transactionRecyclerView;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_transactions, container, false);

    transactionRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rvTransactions);
    transactionRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    transactionRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    lblIN = rootView.findViewById(R.id.qtyIn);

    fetch();

    return rootView;
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView transProductName;
    public TextView transQuantity;
    public TextView transType;
    public TextView transDate;
    public ImageView imgTransTypeIN, imgTransTypeOUT;

    String key;

    public LinearLayout rootTransactions;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        rootTransactions = itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_rootTransactions);
        transProductName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_TransProductName);
        transQuantity = itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_TransProductQty);
        transDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_TransDate);
        transType = itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_TransType);
        imgTransTypeIN = itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_imgTransTypeIN);
        imgTransTypeOUT = itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_imgTransTypeOUT);
    }

    public void setTransProductName(String string) {

        transProductName.setText(string);
    }

    public void setTransQuantity(String string) {

        transQuantity.setText(string);
    }

    public void setTransDate(String string) {

        transDate.setText(string);
    }

    public void setTransType(String string) {

        transType.setText(string);
    }

    public void setImgTransType(String url) {

        if(transType.getText().equals("IN")){
            imgTransTypeIN.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            imgTransTypeOUT.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else if(transType.getText().equals("OUT")){
            imgTransTypeIN.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            imgTransTypeOUT.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    }

}

private void fetch() {
    Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("TRANSACTIONS");

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<TransactionDetails> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<TransactionDetails>()
                    .setQuery(query, new SnapshotParser<TransactionDetails>() {
                        @NonNull
                        @Override
                        public TransactionDetails parseSnapshot(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                            return new TransactionDetails(snapshot.child("Transacted_Product_Name").getValue().toString(),
                                    snapshot.child("Transaction_Amount").getValue().toString(),
                                    snapshot.child("Transaction_Type").getValue().toString(),
                                    snapshot.child("Transaction_Date").getValue().toString(),
                                    snapshot.child("Transaction_Image_Type").getValue(String.class));
                        }
                    })
                    .build();

    adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<TransactionDetails, ViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.list_transactions, parent, false);

            return new ViewHolder(view);
        }


        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position, TransactionDetails model) {
            holder.setTransProductName(model.getTransProductName());
            holder.setTransQuantity(model.getTransQuantity());
            holder.setTransType(model.getTransType());
            holder.setTransDate(model.getTransDate());
            holder.setImgTransType(model.getTransImgType());

            holder.rootTransactions.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    };
    transactionRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    adapter.startListening();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    adapter.stopListening();
}


@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    //you can set the title for your toolbar here for different fragments different titles
    getActivity().setTitle("Dashboard");
    }
}
```

Add Transactions to the database:

```
public class AddTransactionActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button back, transIn, transOut, confirmTransaction;

ImageView imgIN, imgOUT;

EditText transDate;

EditText currentStk, productQty, description;

TextView labelIN, labelOUT, lblImgIN, lblImgOut;

String selectItem, stkHolder, qtyHolder, totalQtyOut, operator, transType, nameHolder, 
titleSupplier, titleCustomer, titleProduct, dateHolder, key, keyholder, descHolder, url;

Spinner selectCustomer, selectSupplier, selectProduct;

int totalQty;

private DatabaseReference databaseRefSold;
DatabaseReference databaseRefSelectItem;
DatabaseReference pushValues;
DatabaseReference databaseEssentialImages;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_transaction);

    back = findViewById(R.id.btnBack5);
    transIn = findViewById(R.id.btnTransIn);
    transOut = findViewById(R.id.btnTransOut);

    imgIN = findViewById(R.id.imgStockIn);
    imgOUT = findViewById(R.id.imgStockOut);
    lblImgIN = findViewById(R.id.tvImgDescIn);
    lblImgOut = findViewById(R.id.tvImgDescOut);

    labelIN = findViewById(R.id.tvSupplier);
    labelOUT = findViewById(R.id.tvCustomer);

    selectCustomer = findViewById(R.id.sCustomer);
    selectSupplier = findViewById(R.id.sSupplier);
    selectProduct = findViewById(R.id.sSelectItem);

    transDate = findViewById(R.id.etTransactionDate);
    currentStk = findViewById(R.id.etCurrentStock);
    productQty = findViewById(R.id.etProductQty);
    description = findViewById(R.id.etProductDesc);

    confirmTransaction = findViewById(R.id.btnConfirmTransaction);

    databaseRefSelectItem = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("PRODUCTS");

    final DatabaseReference mDatabase = databaseRefSelectItem;
    mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //We create an array list to hold the values brought from the database and show them in the spinner
            final List<String> titleList = new ArrayList<String>();

            for(final DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                titleProduct = snapshot.child("Product_Name").getValue(String.class);

                //populate the spinner with that array list
                ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(AddTransactionActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, titleList);
                arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                selectProduct.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

                titleList.add(titleProduct);

                //Click event for each spinner element
                selectProduct.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                        //pass the reference from that value into another snapshot in order to query those values, here you need to get your node id and inside just get your number , name and so on
                        selectItem = titleList.get(i);

                        if (titleProduct.equals(selectItem)){
                            key = dataSnapshot.child(selectItem).getKey();
                        }

                        mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot2) {

                                for(final DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                    if (snapshot.child("Product_Name").getValue(String.class).equals(selectItem)){
                                        key = snapshot.getKey().toString();
                                    }
                                    keyholder = dataSnapshot.child(key).child("Current_Stock").getValue(String.class);
                                }
                                currentStk.setText(keyholder);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                            }
                        });

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });

    transIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            imgIN.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            labelIN.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            selectSupplier.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            lblImgIN.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            imgOUT.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            labelOUT.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            selectCustomer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            lblImgOut.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            operator = "+";
            transType = "IN";

            databaseRefSold = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("SUPPLIERS");

            Query query = databaseRefSold.orderByChild("Supplier_Name");
            query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    final List<String> titleList = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        titleSupplier = dataSnapshot1.child("Supplier_Name").getValue(String.class);
                        titleList.add(titleSupplier);
                    }
                    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(AddTransactionActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, titleList);
                    arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    selectSupplier.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Toast.makeText(AddTransactionActivity.this,databaseError.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
    });



    transOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            imgOUT.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            labelOUT.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            selectCustomer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            lblImgOut.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            imgIN.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            labelIN.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            selectSupplier.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            lblImgIN.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            operator = "-";
            transType = "OUT";

            databaseRefSold = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("CUSTOMERS");

            Query query = databaseRefSold.orderByChild("Customer_Name");
            query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    final List<String> titleList = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        titleCustomer = dataSnapshot1.child("Customer_Name").getValue(String.class);
                        titleList.add(titleCustomer);
                    }
                    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(AddTransactionActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, titleList);
                    arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    selectCustomer.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Toast.makeText(AddTransactionActivity.this,databaseError.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
    });

    confirmTransaction.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            stkHolder = currentStk.getText().toString();
            qtyHolder =  productQty.getText().toString();
            descHolder = description.getText().toString();

            pushValues = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("TRANSACTIONS");

            dateHolder = transDate.getText().toString();
            stkHolder = currentStk.getText().toString();
            qtyHolder = productQty.getText().toString();

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(dateHolder) || TextUtils.isEmpty(qtyHolder)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please fill all fields.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {

                if(operator.equals("+")){
                    totalQty = Integer.parseInt(stkHolder) + Integer.parseInt(qtyHolder);
                    nameHolder = titleSupplier;
                }else if(operator.equals("-")){
                    totalQty = Integer.parseInt(stkHolder) - Integer.parseInt(qtyHolder);
                    nameHolder = titleCustomer;
                }
                totalQtyOut = String.valueOf(totalQty);

                HashMap<String, Object> newCurrentStock = new HashMap<>();
                newCurrentStock.put("Current_Stock", totalQtyOut);
                DatabaseReference data = pushValues.push();
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("PRODUCTS").child(key).updateChildren(newCurrentStock);
                data.child("Transacted_Product_Name").setValue(selectItem);
                data.child("Transaction_Date").setValue(dateHolder);
                data.child("Transaction_Type").setValue(transType);
                data.child("Transaction_Amount").setValue(qtyHolder);
                data.child("Transactor").setValue(nameHolder);
                data.child("Transaction_Description").setValue(descHolder);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Transaction successfully processed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                //closes current activity on successful data send
                finish();
            }
        }
    });

    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
}
}
```

---

How can I add up the sum of all Transaction_Amount values according to those values being IN or OUT?

Notes:

- The transactions recyclerView is in a fragment
- I would like to display the sums in TextViews outside the RecyclerView, but within the same Fragment

Comment: What you mean outside of recyclerview but within fragment ??

Comment: I'm just going to store the sums in  TextView, and not inside the RecyclerView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query might help you retrieve the sum of Transaction amount according to Transaction type. But you have to provide value inside equalTo(). Which type of transaction you want to see.

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

Query query = reference.child("TRANSACTIONS").orderByChild("Transaction_Type").equalTo("IN");
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            int sum = 0;
            for (DataSnapshot snapShot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Transaction transaction = snapShot.getValue(Transaction.class);
                int amount = Integer.parseInt(transaction.Transaction_Amount);
                sum = sum + amount;
            }
            textView.setText("")
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: @ Ashish .But I faced another problem using this code, See here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67245065/14253444)